# Intercept error messages on VMware vSphere client using PowerCLI for .NET

Tags: c#, powershell, error-handling, vmware, powercli

Is there a way to catch the error messages appearing on the VMware vSphere client using PowerCLI for .NET?
I used Project Onyx 2.0 to capture all mouse clicks and obtain code in C#. But if some operation fails, is there a way to print that on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. These error messages are notifications and if you want to "catch" them you need to pull them out of the VMware server, with PowerCLI or with a C# program.